# Can I import a namespace globally without explicitly calling import in each and every function?

Tags: matlab, namespaces

In order to avoid namespace bloating, I use packages. For example, let `Foo` be a function in a package called `FooPackage`

```
function Foo()
   disp('Foo');
end
```

I want to use this function in another function called `Bar`.

```
function Bar()
    InFunc1();
    InFunc2();
    InFunc3();
end
```

this function calls sub-functions. The Naive way is to say explicitly the package name in each call

```
 function InFunc1()
    FooPackage.Foo();
end

function InFunc2()
   FooPackage.Foo();
end

function InFunc3()
   FooPackage.Foo();
end
```

Alternatively I can use an import in each and every function:

```
 function InFunc1()
    import FooPackage.*
    Foo();
end

function InFunc2()
    import FooPackage.*
    Foo();
end

function InFunc3()
    import FooPackage.*
    Foo();
end
```

Both of the ways are exhausting.  The answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748302/what-is-the-closest-thing-matlab-has-to-namespaces) says that thes are the only ways.
Does anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem by using a directory `private`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use a `private` directory. The functions in the `private` directory can be seen only by functions in its parent directory, and they can be called just by their names.

It's not a completely satisfying solution, but that can help.

Comment: Considering the fact that yours answer is the only one, I will accept it, though, as you said yourself, if is not complete.