# How to change the MATLAB path back to the default?

Tags: matlab, path

I was trying to add a toolbox in MATLAB and instead of calling `addpath('path')`, I called `path('path')`.

Now I'm getting a lot of errors, like

if I initialize a variable, I get

```
Error using eval. Undefined function 'workspacefunc' for input arguments of type struct
```

Is there anyway I can restore the default MATLAB path/paths ?

Comment: Can you restart MATLAB?

Comment: yup,, it's working now, didn't try that earlier,, thanks,

Comment: Use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013875/access-m-files-in-a-subfolder-without-permanently-adding-it-to-the-path) for more info on this.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8103-pushd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MATLAB command

> restoredefaultpath

to restore the MATLAB search path to the state at startup.

See [MATLAB documentation for restoredefaultpath here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/restoredefaultpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where on startup, on Windows 8.1 64-bit, Matlab R2014b would show the same error and then no function would work.
In my case, `restoredefaultpath`couldn't be found.

Setting the UserPath in the matlab setting file as suggested elsewhere also didn't help.

The solution was to remove the environment variable MATLABPATH that I had set as a convenience while trying to compile against Matlab libraries.

The error message could be more helpful...