# Adding files in subfolders to sphinx documentation (sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain)

Tags: matlab, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, toctree

I have a directory containing various folders, with each of them having matlab source files in them. Some of these folders have sub-folders containing matlab source files.

How can I create a TOC tree with Sphinx to contain the sub-folders in a nested way?

For example, when `Main-Directory` contains `conf.py`, `index.rst`, and `moduleslist.rst` along with the following folder structure:

```
    Folder1
        abc.m
        def.m
    Folder2
        Folder2.1
            ghi.m
        jkl.m
```

with this `index.rst` file:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    moduleslist
```

and this `moduleslist.rst` file:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

Folder1
=========
.. automodule:: Folder1
:members:

Folder2
=========
.. automodule:: Folder2
    :members:
```

But this does not include the sub-folder `Folder2.1` and files in it. I have tried adding `Folder2/index` in `index.rst`, with the `Folder2/index.rst` containing the automodule for `Folder2.1`, which didn't include documentation of `ghi.m`.

**How can I get Sphinx to show nested sub-folders in it's TOC tree?**

Comment: Related [`Access m-files in a subfolder without permanently adding it to the path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013875/access-m-files-in-a-subfolder-without-permanently-adding-it-to-the-path).

Comment: @IKavanagh and others - another common oversight I see is forgetting to set `matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath(os,path.join('path','to','mfiles'))` without this in `conf.py` Sphinx won't know where to find your MATLAB files. You can **not** just set the Python `sys.path` because that uses `importlib` to find **only** _Python_ files.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to how the parameter are documented in the comments? I wonder if the OP's MATLAB classes, class-methods and functions are documented using Sphinx markup? See [Sphinx Domains](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html) for examples. Typically parameter documentation is given in comments after the first line of the object definition as `:param type arg: the description of the argument`

Answer (score 4):

I've started using Sphinx and have run into this problem on documentation in general (not specific to autodoc feature).  This is how I got it to work and have much better control over how the tree is built.

Treat each folder as a separate group.  So at the Sphinx root directory you'll have the index.rst file that will look like this:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    Folder1/index
    Folder2/index
```

I use the `maxdepth: 1` so that it only list the major group name.

Under Folder1 and Folder2 you'll need to add additional `index.rst` files:

```
#Folder1/index.rst

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    abc.m
    def.m

#Folder2/index.rst

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    Folder2.1/index
    jkl.m
```

As a side note, I've setup my index pages so that they either have just group listings (`maxdepth: 1`) or detail page listings (`maxdepth: 2`) - I'm sure there is a way to make the folder/index at depth 1 and files at depth 2.

Then within `Folder2.1` you'll need your third index:

```
#Folder2.1/index.rst

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    ghi.m
```

Here is the [Sphinx Docs on Nested `toctree`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) and it wasn't as clear.  Obviously you'll need the `autodoc` code for more complicated/deep tree structures.