# How to access functions inside a subfolder that resides inside a private folder?

Tags: matlab

I just realized that MATLAB cannot access functions inside a subfolder that resides inside a [*private*](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) folder.

I have a project that uses several functions from one MATLAB toolbox. In an attempt to make the entire project portable, I extracted the root folder of the toolbox and pasted it inside a *private* folder inside the project folder, so that my project could be executed in a computer that does not have that particular toolbox installed.

However, since the toolbox functions are stored inside many subfolders, this seems to prevent MATLAB from accessing them.

My idea is to preserve the toolbox folder hierarchy as is, instead of spilling the toolbox functions inside the *private* folder.

**Why can MATLAB access functions that reside directly inside a *private* folder but can't access functions inside a subfolder that resides inside a *private* folder?**

**Is it possible to allow access to this subfolder?**

---

For those of you unfamiliar with *private* folders, gnovice has a very good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278206/3599179).

---

### Example:

Take the following simplified version of the problem, where we have:

- Three folders: `Project`, `private` and `toolbox`
- Three functions: `foo.m`, `privateFunction1.m` and `privateFunction2.m`

With the following hierarchy:

[image: private folder toolbox matlab]

### The problem:

`foo.m` can access `privateFunction1.m` but not `privateFunction2.m`.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you want to do, but aren't you looking for `addpath path/to/some/dir/with/code`?

Comment: What operating system are you on? And what do you specifically mean by "private folder"?

Comment: The purpose of using a private folder is that it allows access to its content only to the functions that reside in the parent folder, so you don't need to deal with paths.

Comment: I also have this problem, with subfolders and subsubfolders of the main folder... If you have any solution for those ones I'd appreciate

Comment: It's just not how private folders work. If you insist on maintaining the structure you need to `cd` to the subfolder or add it to MATLAB's path. I'd also highly recommend against copying functions from MATLAB's toolboxes since it violates your licensing agreement.